# How to close a mongodb python connection?

Tags: python, mongodb, connection, pymongo

I'm doing a python script that writes some data to a mongodb.
I need to close the connection and free some resources, when finishing.

How is that done in Python?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Use [`close()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.close) method on your `MongoClient` instance:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()

# some code here

client.close()
```

> Cleanup client resources and disconnect from MongoDB.
>
> End all server sessions created by this client by sending one or more endSessions commands.
>
> Close all sockets in the connection pools and stop the monitor threads.

Comment: And also `disconnect ` is no longer available from pymongo 3.x

Comment: @alecxe, there any way or form of know if the connect daba base closed?

Comment: in Jupyter Notebook, after .close() I'm still able to query the DB. Is it auto-reconnecting?

Comment: @NikhilVJ In the above `answer`, it says: `Disconnecting will close all underlying sockets in the connection pool. If this instance is used again it will be automatically re-opened.`

Answer (score 31):

The safest way to close a pymongo connection would be to use it with 'with':

```
with pymongo.MongoClient(db_config['HOST']) as client:
    db = client[ db_config['NAME']]
    item = db["document"].find_one({'id':1})
    print(item)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause too much traffic when you have a real time application that can perform hundreds of thousands of operations in a matter of minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @alexce's answer, it's not always true. If your connection is encrypted, MongoClient won't reconnect:

```
    def close(self):
        ...
        if self._encrypter:
            # TODO: PYTHON-1921 Encrypted MongoClients cannot be re-opened.
            self._encrypter.close()
```

also, since version 4.0, after calling `close()` client won't reconnect in any case.

```
   def close(self) -> None:
        """Cleanup client resources and disconnect from MongoDB.
        End all server sessions created by this client by sending one or more
        endSessions commands.
        Close all sockets in the connection pools and stop the monitor threads.
        .. versionchanged:: 4.0
           Once closed, the client cannot be used again and any attempt will
           raise :exc:`~pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation`.
```